# What to do to make Metafont stop emitting "! Emergency stop." when i type \relax

Tags: miktex, metafont

Hello I have been trying to learn `Metafont` through the METAFONTbook, but when I try to use the `\relax` command it responds with:

> `! Emergency stop.`

I am using `Metafont ver. 2.7182818 (MikTex 2.9.6630 64-bit)`.

it says that the transcript was written on `mfput.log` and on `mfput.log` it was written:

> `This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit) (preloaded base=mf 2018.4.24)  28 AUG 2018 22:17`
>
> `**\relax`
>
> `! Emergency stop.`
>
> `<*> \relax`
>
> `*** (job aborted, no legal end found)`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Probably Metafont ended with something like `Transcript written on somename.log`. At the end of the file `somename.log` you can find the full error message. Could you add this error message to your question? That would make it much easier to answer.

Comment: The prompt
`**`
means 'input file name'.
If you input `\relax` instead of a file name,
the prompt `*` should appear. It means
'input a command', for example, 'end'.
Thus '! Emergency stop.' shows that the
METAFONT binary is problematic.

Comment: yes but when i type mf --interaction=errorstopmode --screen istead of just mf it works, but it is quite cumbersome to have to write this every time i use metafont.

Comment: Quite old post, but I'm still facing the same problem (Windows 10, ```METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (MiKTeX 22.7)```). As mentioned above, calling ```mf --interaction=errorstopmode --screen``` will "solve" the problem but gets quite annoying especially if you need to call that several times. A little workaround I found is to define a macro with ```doskey mfa=mf --interaction=errorstopmode --screen``` and then call ```mfa```. The macro is local to the command prompt is defined in, hence has to be redefined every time. It may be possible to make it "permanent", but I didn't tried myself.