# METAFONT expects file rather than a command

Tags: miktex, metafont

I was trying to carry out the very first and basic example in Knuth's book
"the METAFONT book":
I typed

```
\relax
```

and then

```
drawdot (35,70); showit;
```

HOWEVER, as the black part of the snippet show, "mf"
shows

```
! Emergency stop.
```

What's wrong with this toy example??

[image]

Comment: That's really odd. The same version of METAFONT (in TeXLive though) works for me...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I use Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) under Win 8.1 Is it a problem ?

Comment: It shouldn't be... I'll ask for someone with MiKTeX to test this...

Comment: see this log file:

Comment: This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) (preloaded base=mf 2015.3.26)  20 SEP 2019 19:56
**\relax
! Emergency stop.
<*> \relax
          
*** (job aborted, no legal end found)

Comment: Hm... How exactly did you run the program? I typed `mf`, then `<return>`, then `\relax`, then `<return>` again. How did you do?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I typed the very same sequence of commands.Right after the \relax command it complains about non-existing file: **\relax ! Emergency stop. <*>\relax Transcript written on mfput.log.

Comment: It looks like a miktex bug to me and I suggest that you add an issue to the issue tracker https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues.

Comment: [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447889/what-to-do-to-make-metafont-stop-emitting-emergency-stop-when-i-type-relax) the question was partially answered.They say that I have to write " mf --interaction=errorstopmode --screen" BUT I do not know why...

Comment: @user2925716 If you're on windows and don't mind building Metafont yourself I have translated it to C++ here https://github.com/nadder/rstex under rsmetafont_win. To follow the book you also need to put plain.mf somewhere where the program can find it and create a base file by running `rsmetafont plain dump`. Now run `rsmetafont -base=plain` and you should be able to follow the examples exactly as in the book.